# Fourier part series, missing one piece

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

$$F(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
ax,&0<x<\pi,\\
bx,&-\pi<x<0,
\end{array}
\right.$$

So, far i've got:
$$a_0 = - \frac{b\pi}{2} + \frac{a\pi}{2}$$
$$bn = \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(a+b)$$

Can someone help me get $a_n$?
I did try, but I don't really think $0$ is the solution.
Thank you.

Comment: $$F(x) = \frac{a-b}{2}\ |x| + \frac{a+b}{2} x$$
for $-\pi<x<\pi$, and probably you can lookup their Fourier series representation somewhere.

Comment: I did try, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$F(x) = \frac{a-b}{2}\ |x| + \frac{a+b}{2} x$$
for $-\pi<x<\pi$. The first part is an even function that corresponds to the $a_n$'s.

Without looking at tables, the formula for $a_n$, $n> 0$ is

$$\begin{align*}
a_n &= \frac2{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{a-b}{2}\ |x|\cos nx\ dx\\
&= \frac{a-b}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi|x|\cos nx\ dx\\
&= \frac{a-b}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^0(-x)\cos nx\ dx + \frac{a-b}{2\pi}\int_{0}^\pi x\cos nx\ dx\\
&= \frac{a-b}{\pi}\int_{0}^\pi x\cos nx\ dx\\
&= \frac{a-b}{n\pi}\int_{0}^\pi x\ d\sin nx\\
&= \frac{a-b}{n\pi}\left\{\left[x\sin nx\right]_0^\pi-\int_{0}^\pi \sin nx\ dx\right\}\\
&= \frac{a-b}{n\pi}\left\{\left[x\sin nx\right]_0^\pi+\left[\frac{\cos nx}n\right]_0^\pi\right\}\\
&= \frac{a-b}{n\pi}\left(0+\frac{\cos n\pi}{n} - \frac 1n\right)\\
&= \frac{(a-b)(\cos n\pi-1)}{n^2\pi}\\
&= \frac{(a-b)((-1)^n-1)}{n^2\pi}\\
&=\begin{cases}
-\dfrac{2(a-b)}{n^2\pi}&n\text{ is odd}\\
0&n\text{ is even, }n\ne 0\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

---

Or it is possible to do the following integration directly, and I don't think it is different:

$$a_n = \frac{2}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi F(x)\cos nx\ dx$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess  I was partly right :)

Comment: @mirai Are you allowed to lookup Fourier series tables? This is much easier to do if you can. The $|x|$ is just a triangular wave, and the $x$ is a sawtooth wave, possibly with scaling and shifting.

Comment: I can look, but i still have to do this.

Comment: @mirai If you think this is helpful, please mark this as an answer.